# How to iterate through next value in python dictionary and append the keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python ordered dict as shown below; I want to create a new dict with same values and put start and end dates as key. If a random value appears in the middle of same values then I want to ignore that random value and continue with my dict. I am learning python, please help.
This is my ordered dict key and values:

```
mydict={
4/24/18 :8.75
4/25/18 :8.75
4/26/18 :8.75
4/27/18 :1
4/30/18 :8.75
5/1/18  :8.75
5/2/18  :8.75
5/3/18  :8.75
5/4/18  :3
5/7/18  :3
5/8/18  :3
5/9/18  :3
5/10/18 :3
5/11/18 :4
5/14/18 :4
5/15/18 :4
5/16/18 :1
5/17/18 :4
5/18/18 :4
5/21/18 :4
5/22/18 :4}
```

What I want is:

```
newdict = [(8.75,(4/24/18,5/3/18)),(3,(5/4/18,5/10/18)),(4,(5/11/18,5/22/18))]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
newdict ={}
startdate = mydict.keys()[0]
firstval = mydict.values()[0]
enddate =0

for index, (key, value) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    if value==firstval:
        enddate =key
        continue

     else:
         newdict.update({firstval: (startdate, enddate)})
         startdate =key
         firstval=value
```

Comment: You have a normal dictionary, not an `collections.OrderedDict`. The default dictionary in Python is **not ordered**. Can you please at least give us valid Python as a definition for your dictionaries?

Comment: `newdict = {(8.75:4/24/18,5/3/18),(3:5/4/18,5/10/18),(4:5/11/18,5/22/18)}` is not a dict

Comment: Put differently: `mydict.keys()[0]` is not guaranteed to be a 'first' key, and will almost certainly be a different key from what you expected it to be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This is a small portion of my dictionary as my data set is very big, I have ordered my keys in the dictionary based on dates as i need them in order of dates.

Comment: @cryptonome Okay, I edited it. I am a beginner learner in python. Can you please help?

Comment: @A.S: You perhaps ordered lines in your source code, but that doesn't mean that the dictionary data structure remembers that order. It doesn't, because dictionaries are not ordered data structures (meaning they are free to re-order key-value pairs as needed to make the storage more efficient). So what you *think* is item number 0 is not actually item 0.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, okay then with a normal dictionary key-value pair is my desired outcome achievable? I am trying to find a way to get output in the above mentioned format. If you can, please help.

Comment: I don't know, because your syntax is not valid Python. I don't know what types those keys are. If they are `datetime.date()` objects, or dates *in ISO 8601 format* (they are not as written) then you can simply sort the keys to get them in date order.

Comment: @MartijnPieters keys are datetime.date()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code fails to initialize `mydict` at all.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior there's no double digit month nor date that isn't zero padded. you also said that `mydict` is your ordered dict, but that's not a dict. the output is also not a dict. you have 2 invalid python data formats in you post, your end output is also ambiguos (is it a list, a dict, tuple in a list, which one?), you need to fix those first.

Comment: errr... scratch that i meant months or dates in digit, not _double digit_, although apparently i was wrong in that particular case, as long as it's string, it's going to be accepted by strptime

Answer (score 1):

```
#Do not use dictionary. Dictionary groups without fixed order
mylist=[('4/24/18', 8.75),
 ('4/25/18', 8.75),
 ('4/26/18', 8.75),
 ('4/27/18', 1.0),
 ('4/30/18', 8.75),
 ('5/1/18', 8.75),
 ('5/2/18', 8.75),
 ('5/3/18', 8.75),
 ('5/4/18', 3.0),
 ('5/7/18', 3.0),
 ('5/8/18', 3.0),
 ('5/9/18', 3.0),
 ('5/10/18', 3.0),
 ('5/11/18', 4.0),
 ('5/14/18', 4.0),
 ('5/15/18', 4.0),
 ('5/16/18', 1.0),
 ('5/17/18', 4.0),
 ('5/18/18', 4.0),
 ('5/21/18', 4.0),
 ('5/22/18', 4.0)]

values = [e[1] for e in mylist]
valuesreverse = values[::-1]
setvalues = set(values)

dates = [e[0] for e in mylist]
datesreverse = dates[::-1]

result = {e:(dates[values.index(e)],datesreverse[valuesreverse.index(e)]) for e in values}

print result
```

Output:

```
{8.75: ('4/24/18', '5/3/18'), 1.0: ('4/27/18', '5/16/18'), 3.0: ('5/4/18', '5/10/18'), 4.0: ('5/11/18', '5/22/18')}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, it is not entirely correct. Value 1 should not have separate dates. Please look at my desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here I created dictionary with strings so I used `strptime()` to convert them to datetime objects, then sorted that list by the second value and then the dates as a secondary sort. From there using `groupby` to group the list by the second value. From here I create `ranges` which is a a list of tuples created from each start and end date we append as we go through our groups.  If any date in any group list is within this range we do not append it to our new list. After we convert our datetime objects back into strings and then use a dictionary generator to create our dictionary.

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
mydict = {
    '4/24/18': 8.75,
    '4/25/18': 8.75,
    '4/26/18': 8.75,
    '4/27/18': 1,
    '4/30/18': 8.75,
    '5/1/18': 8.75,
    '5/2/18': 8.75,
    '5/3/18': 8.75,
    '5/4/18': 3,
    '5/7/18': 3,
    '5/8/18': 3,
    '5/9/18': 3,
    '5/10/18': 3,
    '5/11/18': 4,
    '5/14/18': 4,
    '5/15/18': 4,
    '5/16/18': 1,
    '5/17/18': 4,
    '5/18/18': 4,
    '5/21/18': 4,
    '5/22/18': 4
}

mydict = {datetime.strptime(k, '%m/%d/%y'): v for k, v in mydict.items()}
lst = sorted(mydict.items(), key=itemgetter(1, 0), reverse=True)
new = []
for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(1)):
    ranges = [(i[1][0], i[1][1]) for i in new]
    x = list(g)
    for i in ranges:
        if any(date[0] >= i[0] and date[0] <= i[1] for date in x):
            break
    else:
        new.append((k, (x[-1][0],x[0][0])))
conv = '%m/%d/%y'
new = [(i[0], f'{i[-1][0].strftime(conv)},{i[-1][1].strftime(conv)}') for i in new]
new_dict = dict(sorted(new, key=itemgetter(1)))
print(new_dict)
# {8.75: '04/24/18,05/03/18', 3: '05/04/18,05/10/18', 4: '05/11/18,05/22/18'}
```

Comment: :Thank you for trying, it is not entirely correct. Value 1 should not have separate dates. Please look at my desired outcome.

Comment: @A.S Updated check new output

Comment: value 1 and its corresponding dates should not be in the output at all. The output should completely ignore any value that appears one time in the middle of other same values